# binary file and compatibility standard information - C++ / JAVA

Tags: c++, binary, standards, portability, binaryfiles

I am reading [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_Java_and_C++) on difference btween JAVA and C++. One difference is that C++ offers 'multiple binary compatibility standards'. Could you explain what this means, or hint at a good reference. I have a clue that it means that binary 'written with' C++ is very portable, can be used on any OS or environment. I would like to have confirmation and more precision. What is it all about?

How to generate binaries? What make it not portable?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Compiled C++ programs aren't very portable between different OSes and different hardware, that's for sure. Portably written C++ source code can be compiled for different platforms and will work on them in the same way. As for the article, it's written ambiguously. I have no idea how Microsoft, Itanium and GNU are standards. They are entirely different things to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What does `int` mean, exactly? When calling a function with 2 parameters - do you put the first one first on a stack or last; or do you have a structure on a heap and point to it? Do you allow an unknown number of arguments being passed into a function? How do you treat strings; arrays? Do you allocate on stack, heap, or in a private memory block? Do you mangle function names (to allow for overloads) or use them as input in source code? Do you align members in a structure on 8 bit, 16 bit, or 32 bit boundary?

All those questions (and many more) are making a great deal of difference to how one binary calls another and the answers are not as simple most of the time.

Java doesn't offer much in terms of how exactly a binary layout is being done (as it's a VM, after all) while C++ offers great flexibility to accommodate almost any imaginable requirement out there - thus it "offers binary compatibility standards", unlike Java (in your example)

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses the question.

Comment: Well, can't help that the original question was edited afterwords :(

Comment: Yet the person that asked the question thinks this was the answer... premature downvoting, Alexey?